# What does "(+5V=5, +/-5V=10)" mean in the context of op amp supply voltage?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I've been trying to see what to expect if I use a single supply of 5v on the tl084 op amp and, while reading about it, I came into a small mystery that I can't seem to solve. On the site of Texas Instruments, it says that the tl084 has 7v minimum supply voltage, and 36v total maximum supply voltage. On the side of the name of both fields it says "(+5V=5, +/-5V=10)". Here is the link: http://www.ti.com/product/TL084

I've been trying to understand what that means. I read the spec sheet, but it doesn't say anything about "(+5V=5, +/-5V=10)". Furthermore, the spec sheet doesn't mention the 7v minimum supply (it recommends +5v and -5v supply, but it doesn't clarify if that number applies to single supply). I think I can solve the question of what happens if I supply 5v myself (I'll just try it and do many tests if it comes to that), but now I'm really curious about what does "(+5V=5, +/-5V=10)" mean. I imagine it must not be something terribly useful, but, you know: the more you know, the more you know.

Thank you, good people.

--
Edit

Here is the screen shot that was required:
[Screen shot from http://www.ti.com/product/TL084](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8ADl.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the location on the page:

[image]

It's an example. It's saying if the requirement is 5 V single-supply this spec line will just say "5", if the requirement is split +/- 5 V supplies, this spec line will say "10". In the case of the TL084, the requirement is either 7 V single-supply or +/- 3.5 V, so the spec says "7".

Comment: The TL0xx series normally needs 10 K to 20 K pull up resistors if a single supply is used. This induces an offset current which stabilizes the op-amp, else severe distortion can occur.

Comment: This pull-up resistor goes to the output pins only.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended voltage for VCC+ is 5v minimum and 15V maximum.  The recommended voltage for Vcc- is -5 minimum and -15V maximum.  The however are not the absolute limits.  The absolute maximum for VCC+ is 18V and the absolute maximum for VCC- is -18V.  (I realize there is some confusion when referring to maximums and minimums of negative voltages, but this is how it is written in the datasheet.)

If you look at the next line on the web page, from where your item in question is located you will notice they have listed "Total Supply Voltage (Max) (+5V=5, +/-5V=10)" as 36.  This is  a restatement of the absolute maximimum VCC+ and VCC-, since 18V - -18V = 36V.

From this, you can understand that what is being provided, in the specification in question, is the absolute minimum difference between VCC+ and VCC-, which is 7 Volts.